# How do you type such nice solutions with all the different mathematical notation here on Math.stackexchange?

Tags: soft-question, notation

I am totally lost as to how this is done. I have never used a computer to type solutions nicely. What do I need to download? I want to learn how to type nice solutions like some of the people on this website. Please help me!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a basic tutorial and reference.

Comment: So do I have to download something or do I just type solutions according to what these links say?

Comment: Stack exchange uses a standard for scientific formatting called LaTeX.  As you learn LaTeX, you can type it directly into the solution space in order to get nice looking mathematics.  A place I started was http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:About

Comment: The nice thing is that you don't have to learn all the header stuff that goes into a standard latex doc.